# Future of SMIL(Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language)?

Tags: html, protocols, multimedia, smil

SMIL (Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language) got updated last in 2008, does anyone know if there are better protocol to follow when it comes to synchronizing multi-media files?

Answer (score 3):

SMIL has no natural competitors, so any other solution would rely on scripting. It has support in ePub readers like [Azardi](http://azardi.infogridpacific.com/) as well as most phones with MMS support. The [Timed Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/ttaf1-dfxp/), [Media Fragments](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/), and [Media Ontology](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediaont-10/) specifications address captioning, bookmarking, and indexing audio/video content respectively. No successor for SMIL has been formulated outside of the [Timesheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/timesheets/) draft, which is a resurrection of the [XHTML+SMIL](http://www.w3.org/TR/XHTMLplusSMIL/) proposal that became [HTML+TIME](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/999) in IE and has a JavaScript implementation in [timesheets.js](https://github.com/timesheets/timesheets.js).

In terms of specifications, it's part of both [ePub3](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/SMIL) and the [Messaging API](http://www.w3.org/TR/messaging/) used in [Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozMmsMessage/smil).

In terms of tooling, it's integrated into the [Aeneas](http://www.readbeyond.it/aeneas/) and [tobi](http://www.daisy.org/tobi) projects to sync audio and video.

In terms of software, it's integrated with [JavaScript](http://www.a-smil.org/index.php/JavaScript_integration) and [RS-232](http://www.a-smil.org/index.php/REST_Push_API) and [subtitle codecs](https://wiki.videolan.org/Subtitles/#Subtitles_support_in_VLC).

Comment: Is this still relevant today in 2015?  SMIL looks dead.  I'm working on a project that sends and receives MMS and we are required to use SMIL.  Development resources for it are very sparse.  Many of the links I find are dead.

Comment: @MikeJansen In 2015, it's part of both [ePub3](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/SMIL) and the [Messaging API](http://www.w3.org/TR/messaging/) used in [Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozMmsMessage/smil).

Comment: @MikeJansen As far  as resource availability, a basic site search (smil multimedia site:linkedin.com) returns more than a few results.